# I think it's time to update the "We are Offline" BSOD

Tags: feature-request, design

The current "We are offline" screen on Server Fault when it is down is:

[image]

with it's lovely 1996 DateStmp's.

I think it's time to update the Windows BSOD on the page to something more appropriate for the times:

[image]

:)

Comment: Update the old-style Windows BSOD to a newer ESXi-style PSOD?

Comment: Shouldn't the BSOD represent the underlying architecture?

Comment: @HopelessN00b - We all know Steve, Kyle, Shane, and Greg host these sites on a Windows 2012 VM running on Parallels on Kyle's Macbook Air.

Comment: @ScottPack SE runs a Windows stack, so it does.  Even so, seems like the error details ought to be updated to reflect a site down, rather than just being a generic screenie of a BSOD slapped up there.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - the screen this morning had a statement at the beginning about "offline for maintenance...back up within an hour" or something like that...followed by the generic/canned Windows BSOD and a Linux error screen.  I'm just bored enough to throw a 5 minute GIMP pic together of the Windows one after seeing the date/time stamps.

Comment: @ScottPack Not only do they run Windows stack, they run bleeding edge Windows/SQL. (I follow [Brent Ozar's blog](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/09/microsoft-sql-server-alwayson-ags-at-stackoverflow/).)  So the Old Skool graphic doesn't fit, IMHO.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard If we want to get technical about it, the HAProxy box is the one serving the `50x` error pages, so it'd be the one we'd need platform accuracy for.  But the images on the error pages are a lot more about fun than accuracy ;)

Comment: @ShaneMadden Hee!!!

Answer (score 10):

But Windows XP runs fine! Why do we need to update just because Microsoft says it's end of life?

Besides, nobody will recognize that error message. And we'll have to retrain the help desk.

Answer (score 8):

But but. I LIKE THE CLASSIC BSOD! CHANGE IS BAD!

Answer (score 8):

We could randomize between all of 'em with a smidge of javascript?

- Old BSOD
- New BSOD
- Linux panic
- ESXi PSOD
- OS X Panic
- Old Mac - the bomb restart dialog or sad mac boot fail screen?
- Crash screen from TomTom's phone

What else?

Comment: Guru Meditation Mode!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, baby... give me some VMS OPCOM messages!  http://i.ytimg.com/vi/O1577ss-3qM/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: VMS!  That brings back memories...

Comment: The error screen should be determined or influenced by browser sniffing.

Comment: XScreensaver used to have a module with a nice collection of panic screens. Use all of them :)

Comment: or a javascript pacman game to play while you wait for the site to reload ?

Answer (score 6):

I recommend faux Google search results asking "is Stack Exchange down", showing a (again, faux) search result of a SO/SF question asking the same.  Naturally, the next search result would be the same question on one of the scraper sites.

Comment: Upvoted for evil genius-ness.

Answer (score 5):

Let me me the voice of change:  OH MY GOD I LOVE THE WINDOWS <strike>8</strike> 2012 ONE!!!

I love it so much that I need more exclamation points!!!

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Uh, yeah, I'll stop now, but still.  Hahahaha!

Comment: It's Windows 2012...not 8... ;) ;)

Comment: Hee!!!  Yes, but I've seen it more on 8.  ;) Edited!

Answer (score 3):

In the name of cultural sensitivity let's update it to be the OSX Panic Screen, which helpfully says "You're screwed!" in 6 languages:

[image: You're Screwed!]

Comment: Hah...I like it!